# Apply animate in all div ID from sql

Tags: javascript, html

I have some data in my database 'phpmyadmin' i selected all data but i want to make some animation when user click more info it increase width and height but when i do so it animate the first only not all 
i make it Id cuz i need one product which user select but class make it all animated in the same time, here the code

```js
var $con = $('#con');
 var $conImage = $('#image');
 var $conLink = $('#link');
 var $conLink2 = $('#link2');
 
 $conLink.click(function(){
  $('#con2').css({'float' : 'left', 'margin':'= 10px 5px 5px 18.5px', 'width':'=250px', 'height':'=260px'});
        $con.animate({'height':'+=290px', 'width':'+=460px'},800);
        $conImage.animate({'height':'+=90px', 'width':'+=120px'},800);
  $con.css({position:'absolute'});
  $conLink.fadeOut(100);
  $conLink2.fadeIn(800);
    });
 $('#link2').click(function(){
  $('#con2').css({'float' : 'left', 'margin':'= 10px 5px 5px 18.5px', 'width':'=250px', 'height':'=260px'});
        $('#con').animate({'height':'-=290px', 'width':'-=460px'},800);
        $('#image').animate({'height':'-=90px', 'width':'-=120px'},800);
  $('#con').css({'float':'left'});
  $('#link2').fadeOut(800);
  $('#link').fadeIn(800);
```

```html
<div id="con2">
 <div id="con">
  <img id="image" src="fish/'.$r['image_p'].'">
  <h3>'.$r['name_p'].'</h3>
  <button id="link">MORE INFO</button>
  <h4>Num Of Product :'.$r['id'].'</h4>
  <h4>Details: '.$r['details'].'<h4>
  <h4>Amount: 1GK</h4>
  <h4>Price: '.$r['price'].' P</h4>
  <button id="link2">HIDE INFO</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

i want to apply all animate in all box in 'con' not first on

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand exactly what you tried to explain but I found some issue in your code and I clean it up a little bit.
Notice that:

- jquery relative value width:"=..." in css method do nothing special. It only make sense with += and -= as it increment and decrements the current value.
- you cannot split a pixel in half 18.5px make no sense. Just choose between 18px or 19px. Floating values such 18.5 make sense in other units but not pixel (please anyone correct me if I am wrong)

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {


    var fishPath = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Puffer_Fish_DSC01257.JPG";

    var $con = $('#con');
    var $con2 = $('#con2');
    var $conImage = $('#image');
    var $conLink = $('#link');
    var $conLink2 = $('#link2');

    $conImage.attr('src', fishPath);

    $conLink2.hide(); //hide second link immediately


    $conLink.click(function() {

      $con2.addClass('clicked');

      $con.animate({
        height: "+=290",
        width: "+=460"
      }, 800);

      $conImage.animate({
        width: 220
      }, 800);

      $(this).fadeOut(100, function() {

        $conLink2.fadeIn(800);

      });

    });

    //hide button
    $conLink2.click(function() {

      $con.removeClass('conClicked');

      $con.animate({
        height: "-=290",
        width: "-=460"
      }, 800);

      $conImage.animate({
        width: 150
      }, 800);

      $(this).fadeOut(800, function() {
        $conLink.fadeIn(800);
      });


    });


  });
```

```css
        body {

          font-family: "Helvetica Neue Light", "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue", Calibri, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

        }

        #instructions {

          font-size: smaller;

          font-style: italic;

        }

        #image {

          width: 150px;

        }

        #con2 {

          display: inline-block;

          border: 1px solid red;

          padding: 10px;

        }

        .conClicked {

          margin: 10px 5px 5px 18px;

          width: 250px;

          height: 260px;

        }

        #con {

          border: 1px solid blue;

        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="instructions">
  I have some data in my database 'phpmyadmin' i selected all data but i want to make some animation when user click more info it increase width and height but when i do so it animate the first only not all i make it Id cuz i need one product which user
  select but class make it all animated in the same time, here the code
</p>

<div id="con2">

  <div id="con">

    <img id="image" src="fish/'.$r['image_p'].'">

    <h3>'.$r['name_p'].'</h3>



    <h4>Num Of Product :'.$r['id'].'</h4>
    <h4>Details: '.$r['details'].'</h4>
    <h4>Amount: 1GK</h4>
    <h4>Price: '.$r['price'].' P</h4>

    <button id="link">MORE INFO</button>
    <button id="link2">LESS INFO</button>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks first for edit it's useful, but my main question you do the animate it apply in one product which found in database when i want to apply in all database which come to the button can't work..it animate the first one in database but second don't apply

Comment: which i mean you now apply the animate in one product which it show in your code i want to make two or more to do the same animate when user click more info